# Browse all Trademark images as an image return

Tags: trademark, research

I have a logo design that I want to trademark, in addition to trademarking the design of an invention (as additional IP protection in addition to a patent). I started with a reverse Google image search, and came up empty (good!).

Next, searched the PTO site (http://tess2.uspto.gov/tmdb/dscm/dsc_26.htm#26), found a few possible Division IDs. However the number of results were around 8k each.

My question: Is there a tool that can return long pages of images from the PTO site similar to a Google image search? I found WIPO (http://www.wipo.int/branddb/en/), and though I can upload an image as a filter, I can't seem to wildcard the text field to be empty in order to just search the images. Has to be an easier way, but my searches have come up empty.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about the law. Try https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/support-centers/uspto-contact-center-ucc

Comment: It is a question though about law tools. (Also, been there, not very useful - but I appreciate the link). The main purpose of this site is to help people find hard to find answers so they can help themselves, if there is a better SE to post in please let me know.

Comment: The main purpose of this site is to answer relevant questions. This other SE is obviously better: https://patents.stackexchange.com/

Comment: They have a strict "no trademark discussion" policy. I thought that a SE that deals with the law would have excellent suggestions on legal search tools, both free and gated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the TESS "Free Form search" you can specify one or more design codes (chosen from the USPTO online catalog of them) with or without "design description" fields, and display the resulting images in a matrix by clicking "image list" on the "results" page.

For instance, searching by 080112[DC] results in 1,616 records having designs containing the image of a "pizza". It can be narrowed by any other criteria, including registered or not, dates, owner's location, class of goods, etc.

https://www.uspto.gov/trademarks-application-process/searching-trademarks/design-search-codes